# Import Export Wit TFS17 -Can't see the new fields

Tags: tfs, devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

I imported work item after customize, working by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phDu9a4F7l8 (Import-Export from cmd).
The problem is that I can see the new fields in Visual Studio - Team Explorer. But I can't see this fields in TFS 17.

Visual Studio frame:

[image]

TFS17 frame:

[image]

Code added in wit xml:
Added in 'Fields' section:

[image]

Added in 'Form' sector-, 'Status' label:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You added the new field under the regular layout, in `<Layout>` `</Layout>` section.

You need to add the new field also in the WebLayout, between the tags `<WebLayout>` `</WebLayout>` (it's appear after the `Layout` section, scroll down). the fields configured there different from the regular layout, for example:

```
<Control Label="Company Name:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Test.Test.CompanyName" />
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the respone.
When im trying to add this field in WebLayout->SystemControl
I got this message:
"The required attribute 'Label' is missing.
The element 'SystemControls' has invalid child element 'Control'.
TF237070: Importing the definition failed. The definition you are trying to import did not validate against the schema. Edit the definition, then try to import it again"

But if I do it inside Section->Group - Its working..

Possible that <SystemControl> are not valid to changes at all?

Comment: If you want to add a field in the web layout is must be under section and group. What do you mean about the system control? you want to add a new field not a system field.